# How to change the encoding of wsimport-generated files?

Tags: java, jax-ws

I am using the wsimport ant task of JAX-WS to generate sources based on some wsdl.

However, these generated sources all seem to be UTF-8 encoded. Is there a way to change the encoding of the files wsimport task  produces?

Comment: why exactly do you want not to use UTF-8?

Comment: Because on this project all other java surces are Cp1252 encoded. Mixed source encodings can cause the compiler trouble, especially when using non ASCII characters. So I want the wsimport to generate java sources that are Cp1252 encoded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is somewhat badly documented. WSImport uses XJC (from JAXB) to create Java files and the documentation [here](http://java.sun.com/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBWorks2.html#wp82750) indicates that changing the character encoding in the XML file should suffice (although I have not tried this). If you are content with running JAXB by hand then you can also configure this via the JAXB_ENCODING property on your JAXBContext.

Answer (score 4):

I post with my register account:

Set the environment variable `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` to -`Dfile.encoding=UTF8`

Example in windows:

```
set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF8

c:>wsimport -keep ... file.wsdl
```

Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
parsing WSDL...

Generating code...

Answer (score 3):

wsimport 2.2.9 in JDK 8 has the `-encoding` option that can be used for this. For example:

```
wsimport -keep -s c:\path\to\src c:\wsdl\myService.wsdl -encoding cp1252
```

I can't find this option in either wsimport 2.1.6 (JDK 6) or 2.2.4-b01 (JDK 7).

Comment: It works perfect +1. For me it also works on previous version (2.2.7)

Comment: Worked for me too! +1

Answer (score 2):

If you're using wsimport through ant task using `gradle`, you can simply use `encoding` property specifying the desired encoding in `wsimport`. I tested with wsimport version *2.2.7*

```java
configurations {
   schemaGenerationBeans
}

dependencies {
   // dependencies per compilar schemas
   schemaGenerationBeans 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.2.7'
   schemaGenerationBeans 'com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-ri:2.2.7'
   schemaGenerationBeans 'com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-tools:2.2.7'
}

task generateJaxb {

    ant.taskdef(name: 'wsimport', classname: 'com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport', classpath: configurations.schemaGenerationBeans.asPath)

    ant.wsimport(wsdl: "$projectDir/src/main/resources/somepath/YOUR_WSDL.wsdl",
            wsdlLocation: "/somepath/YOUR_WSDL.wsdl", // relative path for generated classes
            package: 'org.your.package.xsd',
            xnocompile: 'true',
            xendorsed: 'true',
            sourcedestdir: "$projectDir/src/main/java/",
            encoding : 'utf-8' // DESIRED ENCODING PROPERTY!
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the environment variable to `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` to `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8`

Example from terminal in windows:

```
set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF8

c:>wsimport -keep ... file.wsdl

Picked up `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8`
parsing WSDL...

Generating code...
```